# can I decompile a signed and installed android app?

Tags: apk, android-security

I need to store some passwords inside an android app. I have no way around since this particular app cannot do authentication with a remote server.

I was looking at this decompiler:

http://www.javadecompilers.com/apk

yet, I have a simple question that I see different answers online. Is it possible for a hacker to root my client's device, get the application (I assume the apk is inside the device somewhere), run a decompiler and look up the passwords?

Note that this a production app and will be signed and installed through the google store. This is not just an unsigned apk floating around.

thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes someone could take your passwords. Signing your apk won't make a difference.

You can secure your passwords by storing hashes in the APK. Then even if someone decompiles your code and takes the hashes there's nothing they can do with them since they still won't have the plain text to send to the app.

If all you need to do is control access to your signed app then that should be good enough. Though it doesn't prevent an attacker from decompiling your signed apk, modifying it, and recompiling it into an unsigned one. There's no reliable way to stop this, like there is no way to stop video game piracy. But techniques like obfuscation can help.

Comment: It is perhaps worth noting that you do not need to root the device to get the apk. You can do: "adb shell pm list packages -f" to list all of the file paths for APKs